# Problem in selenium [v4.12.0] remote webdriver [Chromewebdriver] get_downloadable_files()

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I am trying to download some files from a website using selenium chromewebdriver.
while I am calling the function "get_downloadable_files()", it shows that "WebDriver" has no attribute called "get_downloadable_files()".

NB:  I am using selenium inside docker. Selenium v4.12.0.

```
def init_driver():

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.enable_downloads = True

    remote_url = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=remote_url,options=chrome_options)

    return driver
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgY7R.png)

Comment: I would request you to add the method definition too.

Comment: Where did you find this method? I believe your error is very clear- where did you find this attribute "get_downloadable_files()"? I don't think that exists